# AsyncTask on fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, fragment

I have a fragment that gets location and shows it in map and also finds the closes station to current location. This fragment I called by another fragment when a button is clicked. So what im trying to do is that, when the button is clicked, the app "Pauses" till location is got and then keeps going on,becuase if not the app crashes due to the lack of location when doing some operations.

I was reading that i should use AsyncTask, but Im not sure if I should use on the fragment with button or on the one with map. I would appreciate any kind of help. If code is needed just mention it and I will post it.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I cant make it....i was reading and coding for hours but i dont find the way. 
THis is what i have till now.

Here, I click on the button and before it opens the map, I want it to get gps, network ....coordinates.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    //Fragment fragment = null;


    getLocation getLocation = new getLocation();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.SearchButton:

            getLocation.execute();

            break;
    }
}
```

Then i have this class and here's what im missing....

```
public class getLocation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{


    protected void doInBackground(String... strings) {


    }


    protected void onPreExecute(String... strings){

   }


    protected void onPostExecute(){
        Home activity = (Home) getActivity();//---> After app gets coordinates from anywhere, it launches next fragment with the map.
        if(activity != null)activity.openMapFragment();
    }
```

}

How could I do this.?

**EDIT 2:**

Let's see if I can give this a better explanation.

On the class where I handle the map, I use location. I connect to google api server and then I just use `GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(True)` and `GoogleMap.getLocation()` . What I want is to get this location on the fragment that calls the map fragment. I know I have to use `AsyncTask` to do that, but I was trying like this, but I cannot make it work:

class getLocation extends AsyncTask{

```
GoogleMap mMap ;
GoogleApiClient client;
Location location;

@Override
protected Location doInBackground(Location... locations) {
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addApi(AppIndex.API)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    client.connect();

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    location = mMap.getMyLocation();
    if(location!=null)return location;


    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Location location){
    if(location != null){
        Home activity = (Home) getActivity();
        if(activity != null)activity.openMapFragment(); // Open next fragment when location is found.
    }
}
```

}

I would like to know what I need to change, add, delete....to make this work.

Comment: Solved. Moved the `AsyncTask` to `Fragment` with map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AsyncTask` anywhere you need, it can be in your `Activity`, `Fragment` or any other class.

For your question first you should check for location availability and than do your work.

For more details have a look at [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: So you suggest, I press button, check for location. When location is found, launch next fragment?

Comment: Yes you should check for NULL then do your calculations

Comment: Hey mate, see if you could give me a hand. I was checking thousands of pages but i cannot make it. I was reading also that intentService might be better for this case. Anyway, im suing googlemaps api to get location. Please help me.

Comment: What do you want, mention it in your question.

Comment: @capie comment chains like this are generally discouraged as they are more of a 1-1 conversation. If your question evolves after receiving an answer, you can edit the question (which I see that you did, thank you), or you can post a new question if your problem has changed significantly. Also, if Haris's answer helped you, you should mark it as the answer.

Comment: @InternetUnexplorer Thanks for your review and I'm sorry if I messed up something but Im a bit dsperate and "Haris"  (I edited again the question, check if you can give me a hand) looks to be the only one willing to help me, that's why I keep this "Conversation". And no, his answer didnt really help so far, that's why i didnt mark it.

Comment: @Capie did you solved your problem or still you need some assistance?